# DNS issue "Nameserver cannot be queried for SOA." - Eurodns registrar

Tags: domain-name-system, soa-record

Recently we purchased a few domains ( on EuroDNS, which we have been using for years), to use as sending domains for emails. Our ESP asked us to point them to their NS.

All went smooth for .com and .fr domains, but we have a .it domain that we cannot point.

Both Eurodns and the new NS support are blaming one another, and at this point we don't know what to do.

This is the error message we get:

Nameserver cannot be queried for SOA.

The most articulate answer we received from our registrar, so far, is this one:

```
Domain: promo-netbet.it
Validation time: 0.286 seconds
Validation status: FAILED
Nameservers associated to the domain name
Nameserver IP addresses
ns0.dns.dotmailer.co.uk. 94.143.104.162
ns1.dns.dotmailer.co.uk. 80.249.108.165
ns2.dns.dotmailer.co.uk. 79.125.127.185
List of tests carried out
Test name Test Status
NameserversResolvableTest SUCCEEDED
NameserversAnswerTest WARNING
NameserverReturnCodeTest FAILED
AATest WARNING
NSCompareTest WARNING
NSCountTest WARNING
CNAMEHostTest WARNING
IPCompareTest NOT EXECUTED
MXCompareTest WARNING
MXRecordIsPresentTest WARNING
SOAMasterCompareTest WARNING
IPSoaTest NOT EXECUTED
```

Any clue on who is to blame, here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [NIC.it](http://www.nic.it/web-whois/) registrar says:

`ns1.eurodns.com
 ns2.eurodns.com
 ns3.eurodns.com
 ns4.eurodns.com`

You may want to take it up with your registrar, since they have not updated the NS records, the fact that `dotmailer.co.uk` is not recognized as an Autoritative server is not surprising.

Comment: Hi Nicw, thank you for the answer. The fact is that our registrar states they "cannot update" our NS for the errors that I reported.

Comment: Who is responsible for updating your DNS records, does your `.it` registrar have a web page where you can update records? If you have a web page where you cana change the owner, tech contact, etc, you should have the possibility to update the records for your DNS servers also. Mi fa strano se non c'e`...

Comment: We update them ourselves. Maybe I was not that clear, whenever we try, we get this error: The nameservers you have declared are more than likely misconfigured:

ns0.dns.dotmailer.co.uk, 94.143.104.162
ns1.dns.dotmailer.co.uk, 80.249.108.165
ns2.dns.dotmailer.co.uk, 79.125.127.185


The following error(s) occured:

Error : Nameserver ns0.dns.dotmailer.co.uk cannot be queried for SOA
Error : Nameserver ns1.dns.dotmailer.co.uk cannot be queried for SOA
Error : Nameserver ns2.dns.dotmailer.co.uk cannot be queried for SOA   -   A me fa strano che succeda solo con IT, gli altri tutto ok!

Comment: Me lo fa strano anche io.. direi che e` colpa deli server di `dotmail.co.uk`. Tell the techs at dotmailer.co.uk that the fault is 100% theirs.

Comment: `dig @ns0.dns.dotmailer.co.uk -t soa promo-netbet.it`
`; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P1 <<>> @ns0.dns.dotmailer.co.uk -t soa promo-netbet.it`
`; (1 server found)`
`;; global options: +cmd`
`;; Got answer:`
`;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 62278`
`;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0`
`;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available`
`;; QUESTION SECTION:`
`;promo-netbet.it.               IN      SOA`
`;; Query time: 10 msec`
`;; SERVER: 94.143.104.162#53(94.143.104.162)`

Comment: `AUTHORITY: 0` means it believes it is not responsible for the domains, `recursion requested but not available` means the domain exists, but external to itself, and I don't have the authorization to ask it to query the proper DNS servers.

Comment: Grazie Nick, I will try again to push them!